# discord.py embed prints list as a string as opposed to separate entries

Tags: python, discord.py

My bot embeds are being posted with the entire list as one string, instead of separated into entries within the same field. I'm very confused as to why this is happening. Any help appreciated!

Code:

```
fcfile = open(".env")
envlist = fcfile.readlines()
fcfile.close()

names = envlist[4].lower()
names = names.strip('\n')
namelist = names.split('.')
namelist.remove('')
print('Listing active carriers')
embed = discord.Embed(title='Tracked carriers')
embed.add_field(name = 'Carrier Names', value = namelist)
print('Sent!')

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: What happens]

[image: What I want to happen]

Comment: Can you send what the file you're reading from looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it pretty much makes sense, the `nameslist` variable is a list. You can join it with `str.join(list)` so it's a string

```py
nameslist = '\n'.join(nameslist) # Joining the list with newline as the delimiter
embed.add_field(name="Carrier names", value=nameslist)
```