# Trying to sort a leaderboard command from highest value to lowest

Tags: arrays, json, discord, discord.py, pycord

I have a leaderboard that I'm trying to sort from the member with the highest count to the lowest count but I cannot seem to do it.
**Leaderboard Code:**

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 20, commands.BucketType.user) 
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
         title="Leadboard",
         description="Your Servers Count",
         color=0xFF000
        )
    with open('messages.json') as file:
         data = json.load(file)
    for key, value in data[f"{ctx.guild.name}"].items():
        try:
            embed.add_field(name = key, value = value)
            embed.set_footer(text="If you feel your message's are not being counted, please get the server owner to send me a dm!")
        except: return
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

**Output:** [Gyazo.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQINg.png)

**And here is a example of what I'm trying to accomplish.**
[Gyazo.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoqWM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final answer :

```py
#your imports [...]

from discord.utils import get
from operator import itemgetter
from tabulate import tabulate

#your declarations [...]

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 20, commands.BucketType.user) 
    listValues = []
    sortedList = []

    embed = discord.Embed(
             title="Leadboard",
             description="Your Servers Count",
             color=0xFF000
            )
    
    with open('dat.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        listValues = new_list = list(map(list, data[f"{ctx.guild.name}"].items()))
        
    sortedList = sorted(listValues, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    strToPrint = ""
    for item in sortedList : 
        strToPrint = strToPrint +"\n"+ item[0] +" : "+str(item[1])  
    embed.add_field(name="Scores", value=strToPrint )
    embed.set_footer(text="If you feel your message's are not being counted, please get the server owner to send me a dm!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

After a few tries on my side, easiest was to make a list of json dictionary, map the list to get keys and values, and turn it into a new list.
Then I convert the list into a string, adding "\n" as delimiter, and converting the score, after it has been sorted, into a string. Finally, I pass the resulting string as value for your embed, and.. voilà :)

Comment: @pluckpik I'm getting "No Module Named Tabulate" this is a problem I've had before. However, operator and itemgetter are working.

Comment: Tabulate is a module to pretty-print tables, you don't need it at all here

Comment: @stijndci Noted

Comment: oh my bad, you can install tabulate by doing in console `pip install tabulate`. Mostly, if someone suggests you to use an import and you get "no module named", try to `pip install` it. As @stijndcl told, it's not an obligation, it's for a more structured print, you can, as said in my explanation, just `ctx.respond(sortedList, embed=embed)`.

Comment: also, depending of number of members, you could have an issue with size of message to send, in that case, make a count of lines you publish. In my case, I opted for cutting lists at 12 members, but it depends of the number of characters you print each time.

Comment: @pluckplk So, what I've got now is the embed, it has all the "([" in it and its repeating itself inside the embed, you have gotten me closer though since it is from greatest to least.

Comment: could you give a picture of your results to get what you mean by "([" plz ?

Comment: [Gyazo Example](https://gyazo.com/f627e9ea0b7aa705627872b230d5d12a) here you go, Tablist was giving a error so I believe I removed it and that might've been what caused this

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure, to be honest i don't play with Embed for now. Maybe do the send in two times, first `ctx.respond(sortedList)` then `ctx.respond(embed=embed)`, and imho you could even remove the embed since it only carries the footer. As I'm seeing it, since we include embed, it prints the result as it was with the embed dict. So from left to right, not from top to bottom.

Comment: I want it inside the embed if you know what I'm saying and I also wanted it listen top down as in the example. I thank you for the help though. I have OCD so everything need to be neat lol.

Comment: oh maybe I found a solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66097102/discord-py-embed-prints-list-as-a-string-as-opposed-to-separate-entries), transform your list into a string, where each row of list is separated by a `\n`. So `scorelist = '\n'.join(sortedList)` and add it to your embed with `embed.add_field(name="Scores", value=scorelist)

Comment: i've edited my answer so you can see where to do that

Comment: Alright, do i need to change/n to anything? cause now I'm getting a error.
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
(sorry for the many questions btw)

Comment: (no problem, if it was too easy there would be no fun :) ). Well, what your interpreter tells you is that you try to pass a list where it should be a string. Issue comes from last sentences. `scoreList = '\n'.join(sortedList)` is supposed to return a string composed of list's elements. Check that you encode the right value, `scoreList` and not `sortedList` here : `embed.add_field(name="Scores", value=scoreList )` and that now you only pass embed=embed in response with `await ctx.respond(embed=embed)`

Comment: I did everything exactly and I'm getting the same error (also if you have discord could we continue on their, its easier for me to read), lol